# Setting up Microsoft Analysis server Mode

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have MS SQL Developer 2014 Edition installed, Windows 2007

Is it possible to setup 2 analysis servers on the same install, on in mode multi-dimension and the other in tabular. Or is it only one mode per setup.

I meant, can I create an instance for the 2nd one or something ?

Any ideas

Purpose: So I can test out SSDT for both forms of mode

Comment: I'd expect you'll get quicker answer on this over at [dba.se] - voted to move.

Answer (score 1):

A server instance of Analysis Services is a copy of the msmdsrv.exe executable that runs as an operating system service. Each instance is fully independent of other instances on the same server, having its own configuration settings, permissions, ports, startup accounts, file storage, and server mode properties.

Multi-instance means that you can scale-up by installing multiple server instances on the same hardware. For Analysis Services in particular, it also means that you can support **different server modes** by **having multiple instances on the same server**, each one configured to run in a specific mode.